# Laravel 4: redirect if item doesn't exists, ModelNotFoundException doesn't work anyway I try it

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm following Dayle Rees' book "Code Bright" tutorial on building a basic app with Laravel (Playstation Game Collection).

So far so good, the app is working but, following his advices at the end of the chapter, I'm doing my homeworks trying to improve it

So, this snippet is working fine for existing models but throws an error if the item doesn't exists:

```
public function edit(Game $game){
    return View::make('/games/edit', compact('game'));
}
```

In other words, `http://laravel/games/edit/1` shows the item with ID = 1, but `http://laravel/games/edit/21456` throws an error since there's no item with that ID

Let's improve this behaviour, adapting some scripts found also here on StackOverflow ([Laravel 4: using controller to redirect page if post does not exist - tried but failed so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483233/laravel-4-using-controller-to-redirect-page-if-post-does-not-exist-tried-but)):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException; // top of the page
...
public function edit(Game $game){
    try {
        $current = Game::findOrFail($game->id);
        return View::make('/games/edit', compact('game'));
    } catch(ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        return Redirect::action('GamesController@index');
    }
}
```

Well... nothing happens! I still have the error with no redirect to the action 'GamesController@index'... and please notice that I have no namespaces in my Controller

I tried almost anything:

1. Replace `catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)` with `catch(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e)`: no way
2. put `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;` in Model instead of Controller
3. Return a simple `return 'fail';` instead of `return Redirect::action('GamesController@index');` to see if the problem lies there
4. Put almost everywhere this snippet suggested in [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage)

   ```
   App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
   {
       return Response::make('Not Found', 404);
   });
   ```

Well, simply *nothing* happened: my error is still there

Wanna see it? Here are the first two items in the errors stack:

1. http://www.iwstudio.it/laravelerrors/01.png
2. http://www.iwstudio.it/laravelerrors/02.png

Please, can someone tell me what am I missing? This is driving me mad...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here are few of my solutions:

**First Solution**

The most straightforward fix to your problem will be to use `->find()` instead of `->findOrFail()`.

```
public function edit(Game $game){
    // Using find will return NULL if not found instead of throwing exception
    $current = Game::find($game->id);

    // If NOT NULL, show view, ELSE Redirect away
    return $current ? View::make('/games/edit', compact('game')) : Redirect::action('GamesController@index');
}
```

**Second solution**

As I notice you may have been using model binding to your route, according to Laravel [Route model binding](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding):

> Note: If a matching model instance is not found in the database, a 404 error will be thrown.

So somewhere where you define the model binding, you can add your closure to handle the error:

```
Route::model('game', 'Game', function()
{
    return Redirect::action('GamesController@index');
});
```

**Third Solution**

In your screenshot, your `App::error` seems to work as the error says `HttpNotFound Exception` which is Laravel's way of saying 404 error. So the last solution is to write your redirect there, though this apply globally (so highly discouraged).

Comment: Hi Jofry, and thanks for the reply! Yes, according to the tutorial I'm using the Route model binding: I just tried method 2 (it seems the clearest to me) but I get a new error: "Argument 1 passed to GamesController::edit() must be an instance of Game, instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given"... Sometimes I regret the old procedural days... :-)

Comment: In that instance, i'd probably resort to the first one. Since the second solution actually passing the return back to the controller action. Is using `->find()` instead of `->findOrFail()` an option for you?